# Copying certain characters from Outlook to a Text Box Failing RegEx

Tags: regex, vb.net, outlook

I have a text box on a Vb.Net Aspx page that is monitored by a line of regex.  Whenever I paste quotations from outlook the validation fails. I'm pretty sure there are issues with other characters as well.

Here is an example of a statement that would fail:
       “hello” or Doesn’t.

Here is the regex I'm using: 
       "^[a-zA-Z0-9~`!@#$%^\&*()_-+=[]:;'"",.?//\| \n\r]+$"

Does anyone know a way to get outlook to copy and paste properly? or to change the regex to deal with these special outlook chracters?

Comment: Difficult to say, without knowing exactly what gets pasted from Outlook.

Comment: yeah, these are the exact quotes that come out of the email from outlook. “hello” compared to "hello".

Comment: Your regex doesn't work at all https://regex101.com/r/kL5cC7/1

Comment: You must include both types of quotes (i.e. 3 quotes) in your regex. Outlook and Word replace normal quotes by typographical quotes. **What are you trying to validate? If you want to allow all characters, don't validate!**

Comment: @Shafizadeh it works perfectly fine for me...

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I want to be able to handle validating what I currently have in my regex plus the addition of quotes that Outlook uses. Or I might take the route of converting "outlook" quotes into the natural quote vb uses.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for other types of quotation marks in Window's Character Map (Start button  > All Programs > Accessories > System Tools > Character Map).

[image]

Fist select *Group by*: Unicode Subrange.
Then in the *Unicode Subrange* list: General Punctuation.

You will see a lot of different quotation marks there. You can select the ones you need and then copy them to the clipboard. Finally paste them into your code.